# Querying for substring using search module in Play

Tags: lucene, playframework

I was trying to use the Search module provided in Play framework, and ran into the restriction
"You cannot use a * or ? symbol as the first character of a search" based on the reference
http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_2/queryparsersyntax.html

Is there any alternative to query for the substring keyword "ice" in String objects such as "nice, rice,.."

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a [QueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html) by setting the [setAllowLeadingWildcard](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html#setAllowLeadingWildcard%28boolean%29) flag.

```
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(...);
queryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
Query q = queryParser.parse("*ice");
```

But you should be aware of performance implications. From the [docs](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#What_wildcard_search_support_is_available_from_Lucene.3F):

> Leading wildcards (e.g. *ook) are not supported by the QueryParser by
>   default. 
>       As of Lucene 2.1, they can be enabled by calling QueryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard( true ). 
>       Note that this can be an expensive operation: it requires scanning the list of tokens in the index in its entirety to look for those that
>   match the pattern.